Redis eviction policy using lua script
I have a lot of data in Redis like
User_DB_1:<user_id> , User_Main:<user_id>, Skills_DB_1:<user_id>
I set the maxmemory to 50MB and write a lua script and run it in Redis that lua file should remove data that has pattern User_DB_1:<user_id> and shouldn't remove any data for Skills pattern
I have tried a lot and I see that each time remove data matches Skills pattern and I run it uses
redis-cli --eval /data/redis_evication.lua
and the output is (integer) 1000
I am trying to know how can I write a lua file and execute it with the expected results
local cursor = "0"
local patterns = {"User_DB_1:*", "User_Main:*"}
local total_evicted = 0
local limit = 1000 -- Limit of keys to evict per script run

repeat
    -- Scan for the first pattern
    local res = redis.call("SCAN", cursor, "MATCH", patterns[1], "COUNT", limit)
    cursor = res[1]
    local keys = res[2]

    for _, key in ipairs(keys) do
        if string.match(key, "^User_DB_1:%d+$") then
            redis.call("DEL", key)
            redis.log(redis.LOG_NOTICE, "Deleted key: " .. key)
            total_evicted = total_evicted + 1
            if total_evicted >= limit then
                return total_evicted
            end
        end
    end

    -- Scan for the second pattern
    res = redis.call("SCAN", cursor, "MATCH", patterns[2], "COUNT", limit)
    cursor = res[1]
    keys = res[2]

    for _, key in ipairs(keys) do
        if string.match(key, "^User_Main:%d+$") then
            redis.call("DEL", key)
            redis.log(redis.LOG_NOTICE, "Deleted key: " .. key)
            total_evicted = total_evicted + 1
            if total_evicted >= limit then
                return total_evicted
            end
        end
    end
until cursor == "0"

return total_evicted```


I wasn't understand how it work, I was think it looks like redisgear that it run auto but no.
lsu file you should run it each time you need to free a memory, and i can't find any thing help me to run evication policy with specific pattern auto.
and to achive that, you need to run lua file in cron job to help you free memory.
there is also one thing, if your cron job doens't run before memory reached the maxmemory, the evication policy will run and delete the data with any pattern.
until now I can't find any way that help me on that.
Edit: The best approach for that is to use another policy like volatile-ttl that will help you in case you need to delete a specific patter
Usage : you will add a ttl for the pattern that you need to be deleted if Redis reached the maxmemory, and don't add a ttl for the values that you don't want to be deleted and using volatile-ttl will delete from the data that has a ttl
you also can read about it in Redis Documentation
